# Know if any Windows CMD batch commands failed

Tags: windows, cmd, error-handling

I'm running a series of Windows batch commands as part of a Jenkins job. I want to know if any of them has failed. Currently the Jenkins job will only see if the last command failed or not. What's the easiest, cleanest way to do that ? Including decent code readability.

I have tried the following (where A-C are individual batch commands)

`A && B && C`

looks ugly

```
set ACCUMULATED_ERROR=0
A
set /A ACCUMULATED_ERROR = %ACCUMULATED_ERROR% + %ERRORLEVEL%
B
set /A ACCUMULATED_ERROR = %ACCUMULATED_ERROR% + %ERRORLEVEL%
C
set /A ACCUMULATED_ERROR = %ACCUMULATED_ERROR% + %ERRORLEVEL%
cmd /c exit %ACCUMULATED_ERROR%
```

looks uglier

Comment: (I've seen programs that return negative errorlevels. And programs that return non-zero errorlevels when successful, even zero for "failed". Just saying...)

Comment: `&&` prevents a following command to run in case the preceding one failed (when it returns a non-zero exit code) – did you mean `&` (unconditional execution) instead?

Comment: No precisely `&&` allows me to keep the last exit code in the chain - which, if any command fails, will be that exit error code. I don't care if the other commands don't get executed. I just want to know if any command in the chain fails.